# m/m/1 Queue Examples

Tags: networking, queue

I am having hard time working on M/M/1 queue (Common queue architecture). I understand that

(lambda)^2/(mu*(mu-lambda)) = the average number of customers waiting in line

the part I am struggling with is that my queue is limited to only 3 clients waiting then anything after that they get dropped. So how do I find my average customers waiting in line now?

Answer (score 0):

Logically, limiting the queue makes certain queue states (i.e > n) impossible. Thus your probability of being in all states < n sum to 1.0.

Doing a simple Google search for "mm1 with limited queue size" the first result is a PDF that answers your question. The paper actually gives usable formulas.